# How to speed real time opencv image processing on android studio

Tags: android

Iam working on opencv real time image matching by using Imgproc.TemplateMatching(),the app was working but it's slow. Any one have idea to help me how ican speed my template matching. 
**this is my MainActivity:**

package com.example.altayeb.myapplication2;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2{
    private static String TAG="MainActivity";
    InputStream stream = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    MediaPlayer md50,md20,md10,md5,md2,mdwelcom;

    Mat mRgba,gray1,gray2,tmpl,outputimage;
    int match_method;
    Bitmap bmp;
    Point matchLoc;
    int count=1;
    Uri uri;


    BaseLoaderCallback mloaderCallback=new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status){
                case BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS:
                {javaCameraView.enableView();
                    break;}
                default:
                { super.onManagerConnected(status);
                    break;}
            }
        }
    };
    JavaCameraView javaCameraView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        javaCameraView=(JavaCameraView)findViewById(R.id.java_camera_view);
        javaCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);

        md50 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplication(),R.raw.fifty);
        md20 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplication(),R.raw.twenty);
        md10 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplication(),R.raw.tensound);
        md5 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplication(),R.raw.five);
        md2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplication(),R.raw.tow);
        mdwelcom = MediaPlayer.create(getApplication(),R.raw.welcom);

        javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(javaCameraView!=null){
            javaCameraView.disableView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(javaCameraView!=null){
            javaCameraView.disableView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
            Log.i(TAG,"Seccessfully");
            mloaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i(TAG,"Not Seccessfully");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_1_0,this,mloaderCallback);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mRgba=new Mat(height,width, CvType.CV_32FC1);
        gray1=new Mat(height,width, CvType.CV_32FC1);
        gray2=new Mat(height,width, CvType.CV_32FC1);
        mdwelcom.start();



    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        mRgba.release();
    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
       mRgba=inputFrame.rgba();
       gray1=inputFrame.gray();
        match(gray1);
      // return match(mRgba);
        return mRgba;
    }
    //Matching Method
    //public Mat match(Mat source){
        public void match(Mat source){


        switch (count) {
            case 1:{
                uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.altayeb.myapplication2/drawable/fifty1");
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.altayeb.myapplication2/drawable/fifty2");
                break;

            }
            case 3:{
                uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.altayeb.myapplication2/drawable/tow1");
                break;
            }
            case 4:{
                uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.altayeb.myapplication2/drawable/tow2");
                break;
            }

            case 5:{
                uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.altayeb.myapplication2/drawable/ten1");
                break;
            }
            case 6:{
                uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.altayeb.myapplication2/drawable/ten2");
                break;
            }
            case 7:{
                uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.altayeb.myapplication2/drawable/twenty1");
                break;
            }
            case 8:{
                uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.altayeb.myapplication2/drawable/twenty2");
                break;
            }
            case 9:{
                uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.altayeb.myapplication2/drawable/five1");
                break;
            }
            case 10:{
                uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.altayeb.myapplication2/drawable/five2");
                break;
            }
        }
        try {
            stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bmpFactoryOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, bmpFactoryOptions);
        tmpl = new Mat();
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, tmpl);
        match_method = Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED;

       // Imgproc.cvtColor(source,gray1,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(tmpl,gray2,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
       // outputimage=new Mat(mRgba.cols() - gray2.cols() + 1,mRgba.rows() - gray2.rows() + 1,CvType.CV_8UC1);
            outputimage=new Mat(source.cols() - gray2.cols() + 1,source.rows() - gray2.rows() + 1,CvType.CV_8UC1);
       Imgproc.matchTemplate(source,gray2,outputimage,match_method);
      //  Core.normalize(outputimage, outputimage, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

        Core.MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(outputimage);
        matchLoc = mmr.maxLoc;
        double minMatchQiality = 0.68;
        if(mmr.maxVal>=minMatchQiality){
           Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + gray2.cols(), matchLoc.y + gray2.rows()), new Scalar(255, 0, 0));
            switch (count) {
                case 1:{ md50.start();
                break;}
                case 2:{md50.start();
                    break;}
                case 3:{
                    md2.start();
                    break;
                }
                case 4:{
                    md2.start();
                    break;
                }

                 case 5:{
                    md10.start();
                    break;
                }
                case 6:{
                    md10.start();
                    break;
                }

                case 7:{
                    md20.start();
                    break;
                }
                case 8:{
                    md20.start();
                    break;
                }
                case 9:{
                    md5.start();
                    break;
                }
                case 10:{
                    md5.start();
                    break;
                }
            }}
        else    {
            if(count>=10){count=1;}
            else {count++;}
        }
       // return  mRgba;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id=item.getItemId();
        if(id==R.id.about){
            Intent i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),About.class);
            startActivity(i2);
        }
        if(id==R.id.help){
            Intent i3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Help.class);
            startActivity(i3);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class CustomizableCameraView extends JavaCameraView {

        public CustomizableCameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public void setPreviewFPS(double min, double max){
            Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
            params.setPreviewFpsRange((int)(min*1000), (int)(max*1000));
            mCamera.setParameters(params);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. Check the size of the captured photos. If they are very large, template matching is going to take a lot of time. Reducing the image size speeds up matching, just that you will have to resize your templates as well.
2. See whether you really need to do template matching on the entire image. Cropping out only the real region of interest, if there is one, can help a lot.
3. You can also do some profiling to see where exactly the bottlenecks are. Is the program still slow even if you do not perform template matching?

Comment: Ok, on camera frame how ican resize the image which it not Square